# Finding inverse of the rational fucntion

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find the inverse of $f(x)=\frac{2x-1}{x(x-1)}$. So far I figured out that the domain should be (0,1) and the range is R itself. I found that by drawing a graph after I turned the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x-1}$. since function is 1-1 and onto between this domain and range I know this function must have an inverse. But i could not go further after the following point.

$f(x)=y=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x}-1$ and I exchange the $y$ and $x$ and get $x=\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{y}-1$ and after that point I know I should solve it with respect to $y$ but I could not any help will be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: I rewrote it please see the question

Comment: is the function given as $f(x)=\frac{2x-1}{(x(x-1))}$?

Comment: Switch $x$ and $y$ and then solve for $y$. Then you will have th inverse...

Comment: that is the problematic part I could not solve for y.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: yes that is the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace $y$ and $x$ to get the inverse function

$$x=\frac{2y-1}{y(y-1)}$$

Now we have to algebraically manipulate the equation to get something in the form $y=\ldots$

$$x(y^2)\,\underbrace{-xy-2y}_{y(-x-2)}+1=0$$

Solving the equation in terms of $y$, we get

$$y=\frac{x+2\pm\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2x}$$

Comment: thanks appreciated for the answer.

Comment: I have one more question. Can a fucntion have more than one inverse? or we should choose one of our solution as a solution

Comment: Every function has only one inverse. If you the plus minus confuse you, think of the inverse of $y=x^2$, which is $y=\pm\sqrt{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

Solve for set $f(x)=y$ and solve for $x$. Eventually you will get a quadratic polynomial:

$$x^2+(-1-\frac{2}{y})x+\frac{1}{y}=0$$

Use the quadratic root-finding formula to get $x$ in terms of y.

At the end, substitute $f(x)$ for $x$ and $x$ for $y$.

Answer (score 0):

If
$y = \frac{2x-1}{x(x-1)}
$,
$yx(x-1) = 2x-1$
or
$yx^2-yx-(2x-1) = 0$
or
$yx^2-(y+2)x+1 = 0
$.

Applying the quadratic formula,
the discriminant
$D^2
=(y+2)^2-4y
=y^2+4y+4-4y
=y^2+4
$
so the roots are
$x
= \frac{y+2\pm D}{2y}
= \frac{y+2\pm \sqrt{y^2+4}}{2y}
$.